# What sections get called during compiling and actual run time

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I am working on an Installer project using InnoSetup. I already get it working but just one thing I am still not 100% convinced is that

For sections "[Setup][InstallDelete][Files][Dirs][Icons][INI][Registry][Run][UninstallRun][UninstallDelete]"

- What sections will be processed during compiling time(developer builds the Setup.exe)?
- What sections will be processed during actual run time(user installs to their machine).

The reason I ask is that when I want to set desktop shortcut to be a specific icon, I have following line of code

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\MyProgram"; Filename: "{app}\MyProgram.exe"; IconFilename: "D:\Icon\MyIcon.ico"
```

Then I run the installer on a virtual machine for testing and found out the shortcut does not have the icon I specify. Because my original thought is that `[Icons]` will be run during compiling time then load the icon file and remember it.

I manage to set the shortcut icon by using this line of code

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\MyProgram"; Filename: "{app}\MyProgram.exe"; IconFilename: "{app}\MyProgram.exe"
```

But I would still like to know more about how each InnoSetup sections work.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call it *"running"*, but if I accept your terminology – All sections are run on run time (install time or uninstall time).

Except for `[Setup]` which is definitely not run as a whole. Each directive in the Setup section is specific.

---

*Anyway, this look like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/257963). You better ask a specific question about your specific icon problem*.

Comment: I have resolved the Icon issue but if you take "[Files]" as example, it must be called during the compiling time otherwise how come the installer would get the required files when user installs the software in their own computer.

Comment: Well, as I wrote, it's not called. It processed somehow. All sections are somehow processed both on compile and run time. So for example the `[Files]` section when processed on compile time, packs the files. And when processed on run time, it unpacks them.